# Spring Boot and OAuth2 integration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

What is the best way to integrate my Spring Boot app with OAuth2? It already has login functionality with issuing a JWT token. What I want to achieve: perform login using OAuth2 and issue the same JWT to access my app.

What should I use:

1. Keycloak auth server + make my app a resource server
2. Write my own auth server using spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure and spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client + make my app a resource server?
3. Any other approach you can suggest...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, this link can help you: https://stackshare.io/stackups/keycloak-vs-spring-security

It really depends on your scenario.

But, in my opinion, the first option has more advantages. The main one is the maintenance effort. With your own oauth server, you must maintain one more service. Keycloak is mature and open source, with many developers maintaining it.

Comment: Agree. Keycloak is well documented, maintained and feature-rich (stuf like federation of user identities from many providers can be very useful). You can have a look at [spring-security-oauth2-webmvc-addons](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/webmvc/spring-security-oauth2-webmvc-addons) for resource-server integration (Keycloak adapters are [deprecated](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187)).